# NAudio, recording multiple line in

Tags: naudio

I need to capture audio of multiple Line In. As i understand it should be done with WaveMixerStream32 class, but can not figure out how to initialize multiptle WaveIn as WaveStream to pass them to AddInputStream method of WaveMixerStream. 
I am able to record audio of single linein with code:

```
waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveIn();
waveIn.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(44100, 1);
waveIn.DataAvailable += new EventHandler<NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs>(audioDataAvailable);
waveWriter = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter(wavFileName, waveIn.WaveFormat);
waveIn.StartRecording();
```

Comment: Could you please provide your solution if you have complete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach, if possible, is to capture them all separately to files and then mix later.

If you must mix on the fly, create a BufferedWaveProvider for each WaveIn, and write samples as they become available. Then those BufferedWaveProviders can all be added into a MixingSampleProvider (assuming they are all the same channel count and sample rate). The tricky bit will be to decide when to read from the MixingSampleProvider. Ideally you want each instance of WaveIn to have deposited one buffer full of audio in its BufferedWaveProvider, and then pull that amount of audio through the mixer. You could have a timer that ticks and pulls through the MixingSampleProvider whenever all the BufferedWaveProviders have a certain amount of data in them.

Comment: Thank you. I will try "easiest" approach.

P.S. Thanks for NAudio library, brilliant work.

Comment: Great answer! I'm currently implementing the second mentioned approach - is it safe to call `ClearBuffer` on those `BufferedWaveProviders` after I read from all of them using the `MixingSampleProvider`? I want to keep the memory footprint as low as possible.

Comment: `ClearBuffer` doesn't free any memory. BufferedWaveProvider simply has a buffer of a fixed size (usually 5 seconds).